# AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'voice'

Tags: python, discord.py

An error occurred while creating the bot using the discord py. This is a music bot, and when you enter a playback command, the following error appears:`AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'voice'` The code is as follows:

```
if message.content.startswith("<<play"):
        for vc in client.voice.clients: #AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'voice'
            if vc.guild == message.guild:
                voice = vc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not

```py
client.voice.clients
```

It's:

```py
client.voice_clients
```

#### Reference:

- [`Client.voice_clients`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.voice_clients)